# onrowaction updating all the rows

Tags: lightning

I want a negative and positive button to increment a quantity field on a data table. I got it built out but when the buttons are pressed it updates every row on the table. How do i get it to only update the actioned row?:
Cmp:

```
<aura:component >

<aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="keyField" type="String" default="id"/>
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="errors" type="Object" default="[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="draftValues" type="Object" default="[]"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>
<div style="height: 100%">
    <lightning:datatable aura:id="dtTable"
                         columns="{! v.columns }"
                         data="{! v.data }"
                         keyField="{!v.keyField}"
                         errors="{! v.errors }"
                         draftValues="{! v.draftValues }"
                         onsave="{! c.handleSaveEdition }"
                         onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"
                         />
</div>
```

Controller

```
({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.set('v.columns', helper.getColumnDefinitions());
        helper.fetchData(cmp,event, helper);
    },
    handleSaveEdition: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var draftValues = event.getParam('draftValues');
        console.log(draftValues);
        var action = cmp.get("c.updateAccount");
        action.setParams({"acc" : draftValues});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    },
    handleRowAction: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    var action = event.getParam('action');
    var row = event.getParam('row');
    switch (action.name) {
        case 'down':
            helper.down(cmp, row);
            break;
        case 'up':
            helper.up(cmp, row,action);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
})
```

Helper

```
    ({
    getColumnDefinitions: function () { 
        var columns= [
            {label: 'Product', fieldName: 'ProductName', type: 'text' , editable: false, fixedWidth: 250},
            {type:  'button-icon', fixedWidth:53, typeAttributes: {
                iconName: 'utility:down',
                name: 'down',
                disabled: false,
                iconPosition: 'Center',
                fixedWidth:53
            }},
            {label: 'Quantity', fieldName: 'Quantity__c', type: 'number' ,editable: true, fixedWidth: 100, cellAttributes: { alignment: 'center' }},
            {type:  'button-icon', fixedWidth:53, typeAttributes: {
                iconName: 'utility:up',
                name: 'up',
                disabled: false,
                iconPosition: 'Center',
                fixedWidth:53
            }},
        ];
            return columns;
            },
    fetchData: function (cmp,event,helper) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.shipcat");

        action.setParams({
            storevisitId : cmp.get("v.recordId")
        })
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var data = response.getReturnValue();
                for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    var row = data[i];
                    if (row.Product__c) row.ProductName = row.Product__r.Name;
                }
                cmp.set('v.data',data);
            }
            // error handling when state is "INCOMPLETE" or "ERROR"
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    down: function (cmp, row) {
        var data = cmp.get('v.data');
        data = data.map(function(rowData) {
            if (rowData.id === row.id) {
                switch(row.Quantity__c){
                    case 0:
                    rowData.Quantity__c = 0; 
                    break;
                    default:
                    rowData.Quantity__c = rowData.Quantity__c-1;
                    break;
                }

            }
            return rowData;
        });
        cmp.set("v.data", data);
    },
    up: function (cmp, row) {
        var data = cmp.get('v.data');
        data = data.map(function(rowData) {
            if (rowData.id === row.id) {
                switch(row.Quantity__c){
                    default:    
                    rowData.Quantity__c = rowData.Quantity__c+1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return rowData;
        });
        cmp.set("v.data", data);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're fetching records from a query. Javascript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. As such, the field's name should be Id, not id.

Side note, you can simplify your code:

```
// down logic
var selectedRow = data.find(rowData=>rowData.Id===row.id)
selectedRow.Quantity__c = Math.max(0, selectedRow.Quantity__c - 1);

// up logic
var selectedRow = data.find(rowData=>rowData.Id===row.id)
selectedRow.Quantity__c = selectedRow.Quantity__c + 1;
```

Comment: thank you, those both worked